# CSS: Which property should I use here to break the line?

Tags: css, html-lists

Take a lot at the fiddle below and you would observe that when the line is about to end, the `li` elements break abruptly. Like, in the first line, after 4 `li` elements, the next `li` element breaks and the red circle comes in the same line while the text part moves to the next line.

Here is how I have defined the list elements in CSS:

```
.popular ul li:before {   // Its this part of the code which is making the things
 content: "\2022  ";      // happen like this. If I remove this part, everything
 color:red;               // works fine.
}

.popular ul li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 4px 7px 4px 5px;
  background-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:2px solid #dcdcdc;
}
```

Here is the JsFiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/e7rjW/.

Could someone please tell me how to correct this thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the display:inline to inline-block

```
.popular ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 7px 4px 5px;
  background-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:2px solid #dcdcdc;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e7rjW/5/

Comment: You also need to remove `margin-top` from `a`, as in your fiddle

Comment: Yes, it's already done in fiddle. I kept `margin-top: 0px;` to let OP know what change has done there, otherwise it can be removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `.popular ul li:before` with `.popular ul li a:before` in the CSS fixes your issue.

See [the updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7rjW/2/).

**EDIT:** This doesn't work correctly in Chrome, as pointed out by @Nagarjun:

http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/6770/o7g.png

So you'll probably want to use his answer.

Comment: Advantage over `display: inline-block` on `li` is that the bullet is part of the link and thus is clickable

Comment: The last element on first line is still broken in your fiddle. check.

Comment: @Nagarjun I don't see that, no matter what I resize my browser window to. Could you post a link to a screenshot?

Comment: I see. I can't find an easy way to fix this, and your answer works anyway... So I'll just edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/e7rjW/6/

replace this classess

```
.popular ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 4px 7px 4px 5px;
    background-color:#ededed;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px solid #dcdcdc;
    text-wrap:none;
    float:left;
}


.popular ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color:#777;

    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:700;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0 1px 7px #fff;

}
```